# Inserting character after word using regular expression in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file with 3 lines.

```
secure file#123 status open
non secure file#768-m status closed
file#abc-123 status open
```

How to get following output with `|` added after the word containing `#` character

```
secure file#123 | status open
non secure file#768-m | status closed
file#abc-123 | status open
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
perl -pe 's/(#\S+)/\1 |/' file
secure file#123 | status open
non secure file#768-m | status closed
file#abc-123 | status open
```